# Different output of Python code converted from MATLAB

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, for-loop

I am working on translating the following code from MATLAB to Python. MATLAB code as following:

```matlab
for vfct=1:maxit
    

    EVmat = kron((reshape(Vold,pnum,mnum)*(pr_mat_m'))',ones(pnum,1));
   

    RHSmat = Rmat + beta*EVmat;
    

    [V,polind] = max(RHSmat,[],2);
    pol = pgrid(polind);
    
   
    solerr = max(abs(V(:)-Vold(:)));
    polerr = max(abs(pol(:)-polold(:)));
    

    if (mod(vfct,5)==1) 
        disp(['For iter ' num2str(vfct) ', VF error = ' num2str(solerr)])
    end
    

    if (solerr<soltol)
        break
    end
    

    Vold = V;
    polindold=polind;
    polold = pol;
end
```

My attempted Python code below:

```py
for vfct in range(1,maxit+1):
  EVmat = np.kron((np.dot(Vold.reshape(pnum,mnum) , pr_mat_m.T)).T,np.ones((pnum,1))) 
    
  RHSmat = Rmat + beta*EVmat;

  V, polind = RHSmat.max(1),np.argmax(RHSmat,axis=1) 
  pol = pgrid[polind] 

  solerr = np.amax(abs(V[:]- Vold[:])) 
  polerr = np.amax(abs(pol[:]- polold[:]))

  if vfct % 5 == 1:   
    print(f"Error at iteration {vfct} is kkk {solerr}.")

  if solerr < soltol:
    break

  Vold = V;
  polindold=polind;
  polold = pol;
```

However, my results turn out to be very different from what MATLAB produced. But I couldn't find any problems. What is causing the difference in output?

Comment: If I tested these codes I'd compare the  variables line by line.

Comment: Please read [mre]. We cannot run your code because we don’t know what values all these variables have. We also don’t know what the code is supposed to do. If you want help, you will need to help people to help you.